# Why console.log dose not working in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

## Enviorment

$ node -v
v8.16.2
$ npm -v
6.4.1

```
    "vue": {
      "version": "2.5.16",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vue/-/vue-2.5.16.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-..."
    },
    "nuxt": {
      "version": "1.4.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/nuxt/-/nuxt-1.4.1.tgz",
     ...
    },
    "webpack": {
      "version": "3.12.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-3.12.0.tgz",
    ...
    },
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": {
      "version": "0.4.6",
     ...
    }
```

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Complete</h2>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'NuxtError',
  props: {
    error: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log('created');
    nextUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    console.log(nextUrl);

    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

## Problem

console.log not working.

## Try

- Search "drop_console" in all source
  ->none
- Search "UglifyJsPlugin" in all source
  →none
- Write "process.env.DEBUG = 'nuxt:*'"
  →not working

## Wish

Please tell me resolve.
Please teach me about require code for ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get an error? If so what does the error say?

Comment: No error. I hope that i get console.log message.

Comment: Make sure to restart main `nuxt` cli command - I've been adding console logs all around the place and they were not showing up in cli until restarted cli process. 
Same seems to happen even for subsequent visits - component server console logs are outputted only on first run for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

ESLint throws the error because it has some rules for the console, so you can try:

```
/ * eslint-disable no-console * /
console.log ('hello world');
```

or instead:

```
window.console.log ('Hello world');
```

To configure it globally, open `package.json` and put:

```
"eslintConfig": {
...
"rules": {
  "no-console": "off"
},
```

and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, later I figured I had `quiet: true` set in my build config of `nuxt.config.js`.